# Can I build the vsto project in excel file

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have faced the following problem: if I write an extension in Visual Studio for Excel file, it saves as the .vsto file in the same location and then uploads in the Excel file on run. But I need .vsto file to be automatically uploaded, when the Excel file starts to execute, and not visible to a person, to whom I will pass the excel file.

Is there any way to do this? I want to place USB-key checking code in the VSTO workbook project (Excel file will be unprotected and opened only if there is a USB-key in the USB-port)

In case you need further clarifications, please do not hesitate to ask in this thread

Answer (score 0):

There is no support in VSTO for embedding your code inside an Excel workbook.
The easiest way of embedding code in a workbook is by using VBA.

Otherwise you would need to find a way of forcing your VSTO code and the workbook to be in the same location.